# Should I acknowledge funding from an unrelated project?

Tags: funding, acknowledgement

I hold a research position at a university where I'm working on a certain project in a certain field. I met another professor from another field and began working on a new project with him. I'm submitting our work for publication and I'm unsure whether I should acknowledge funding from my position in the question: “Is there funding to report for this submission?”

I haven't been paid for this particular project but my stipend is basically my livelihood so I'm in two minds about whether to acknowledge it or not.

Comment: Many journals have detailed statements about how to answer this, for instance PLOS has guidelines which include the statement: "Authors are not required to provide the complete list of every single grant that supports them if the grant is not related to the research published". However this may not be the same for all journals, so try and check with them. https://journals.plos.org/plosone/s/disclosure-of-funding-sources

Comment: Add a few words @StuartF, and you probably have the best available answer. I recommend formalizing the answer.

Answer (score 4):

In general, only funding related to the research submitted has to be disclosed. The situation that you are funded through one project and also work on another is quite common. Yet the fact that you are paid in some way doesn't necessarily affecct the funding acknowledgements for the papers. The funding refers to projects, not to persons.

If the professor from the other department has received some kind of grant for the research that he has been doing with you, on the other hand, you would need to disclose that funding.